# How should I thank the professor who let me know of something?

Tags: paper-submission, editors

I have recently submitted the abstract for a journal. After a couple of months, its editor emailed me and told me that my email was in her junk folder. Also, she asked me to resend the abstract. Is it ok to say, "Thank you to take the time to notify me," in the beginning of my email? I want to thank her.

Comment: 1. This doesn't sound like a legitimate journal as those don't do email submissions. And you encountered one of the reasons for this. 2. "a couple of months" is not "recently". 3. No, you should not thank them for this. You should be graceful and understanding of their technical issues. I would expect that the editor actually apologized in their email.

Comment: If the editor knew that the e-mail was in the junk folder, then why didn't they just access the e-mail and get the abstract?

Comment: @Roland: *"This doesn't sound like a legitimate journal as those don't do email submissions"* I cannot judge whether this claim is correct in your field, but it is not correct in general. For instance, there are legitimate journals in pure maths that accept and expect submissions via email [(example)](https://www.springer.com/journal/233).

Comment: Please explain why you think this isn't something OK to say.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I haven't figured out why so many people are anti-thank you [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/185370/69206) either. Perhaps in this case though it may feel like "Thank you for doing your job, *barely*". At a bare minimum they  should be set up with an email address that does not hide legitimate submissions for months, or a procedure like "check the (blasted) spam folder daily for misplaced submissions". I would not thank someone for discovering just now their own incompetence. Further, it may not even be the real reason for the delay.

Comment: To me, "It went into the spam folder and we forgot to check it" feels more like "The dog ate my homework". I don't think that "Thank you for taking the time to tell me about your dog" sends the right message.

Comment: @MahsaTmri I don't understand; the editor said that they found it in their "junk folder" (do you mean spam folder?) and you should send it again; why can't they just move it back out to their inbox folder and preserve the original date of submission? I feel it's strange that they would want you to submit again dated months later if they already have your submission. I can't think of a good reason but I can think of a few bad ones.

Comment: @uhoh Be careful not to put words in OP's mouth. The question doesn't say "How to express my annoyance," it says "Is it OK to say X, I want to thank her." I don't see any reason why this would be objectionable in the slightest so I'd prefer it if OP clarified because it sounds like an XY problem potentially.

Comment: It would ultimately be bad if we just filled up with "is this exact phrasing OK in this exact situation" questions.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Totally agree. An even more striking example is [this one](https://www.springer.com/journal/209).

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I don't think the onus is upon the OP alone to demonstrate to you why they don't think it's okay, because at the time you wrote that comment there were already some obvious reasons why it might not. At least that's my best reconstruction of my "state of mind" at the time I wrote that comment. However I think this is now diverging into a conversation that doesn't contribute constructively to the post.

Comment: @uhoh If you say so

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that this is not a first or second class academic journal, but you probably know that. Since you have to communicate with the professor anyway, there is no reason not to thank her for noticing.

Comment: What is a "first or second class" journal, and how do you know that the journal in the question is not one of them?

Comment: Because good journals do not ask for submission of abstracts (!) via emails.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the circumstances, I would agree that her email should have contained an apology, but considering it is academia, I would agree that starting out the email with "Thank you for taking the time to notify me" makes sense.